# split on delimiter from the end of the string fixed number of times

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:4, strings = c('ooss_bboo_foo','ee_bbbbee_fffee','aas_baa_ffaa_daa', 'iisss_bbbbii_ffffii_dii_mii'))
```

I want to split on `_`, producing new columns (or a new data frame, doesn't really matter). Number of occurences can be estimated with `min(lengths(strsplit(df$strings, "_")))` and `max(lengths(strsplit(df$strings, "_")))`

Desired output:

```
  X1                   X2       X3
1 ooss                 bboo     foo
2 ee                   bbbbee   fffee
3 aas_baa              ffaa     daa
4 iisss_bbbbii_ffffii  dii      mii
```

I've tried multitude of regex's already and I'm pretty desperate already...

Comment: `do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$strings), '_(?=[a-z]+$)|_(?=[a-z]+_[a-z]+$)', perl = TRUE))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posited a "brute force" `stringi` version. Since the OP decided to add color commentary, here's a comparison between the accepted answer and this one (I was wrong in my deleted comments, mine's faster than the "fewer but still extra package" answer, if that sort of thing is important to folks):

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(gsubfn)
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

df <- data.frame(a=1:4,
                 strings=c('ooss_bboo_foo',
                           'ee_bbbbee_fffee',
                           'aas_baa_ffaa_daa',
                           'iisss_bbbbii_ffffii_dii_mii'))

str_split_right_fixed <- function(str, pat, n) {
  stri_reverse(df$strings) %>%
    stri_split_fixed(pat, n) %>%
    map_df(function(x) {
      data.frame(rbind(rev(stri_reverse(x))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    })
}

gsubfn_split_fixed_right <- function(str, pat, n) {
  pat <- paste(rep("(.*)", n), collapse = pat)
  read.pattern(text = as.character(str), pattern = pat)
}

tab_split_fixed_right <- function(str, pat, n) {
  repl <- paste(paste0("\\", 1:n), collapse = ",")
  read.table(text = sub(pat, repl, str), sep = ",")
}

microbenchmark(str=str_split_right_fixed(df$strings, "_", 3),
               gsb=gsubfn_split_fixed_right(df$strings, "_", 3),
               tab=tab_split_fixed_right(df$strings, "_", 3),
               times=1000) -> mb

autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of possible solutions:

**1) read.pattern** `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package can do that directly producing a data frame result.  No other packages are used.  It uses a particularly simple regular expression.

First we create the pattern, `pat`. For example, if `k` is `3` then `pat` is `"(.*)_(.*)_(.*)"` .  Then, simply run `read.pattern` to produce the resulting data.frame:

```
library(gsubfn)

strings <- as.character(df$strings) # ensure it's character, not factor
k <- min(lengths(strsplit(strings, "_"))) # from question

pat <- paste(rep("(.*)", k), collapse = "_")
read.pattern(text = strings, pattern = pat, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
                   V1     V2    V3
1                ooss   bboo   foo
2                  ee bbbbee fffee
3             aas_baa   ffaa   daa
4 iisss_bbbbii_ffffii    dii   mii
```

**2) sub/read.table**.  Relative to the prior solution this solution involves an extra step (the `sub`/`repl` part); however, it uses no packages at all.  It makes use of `strings`, `k` and `pat` from above.  In the case of `k` equal to 3 the value of `repl` would be `"\\1,\\2,\\3"` .

```
repl <- paste(paste0("\\", 1:k), collapse = ",")
read.table(text = sub(pat, repl, strings), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

giving the same result.  The two instances of `","` could be replaced with any character not found in the data.

**Note:** In the solutions above we used `as.is = TRUE` to make the output columns character but if factor is OK then this argument could be omitted.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why it splits from the end and not from the beginning? Is the trick in `pattern` or `read.pattern`?

Comment: regular expressions are greedy so the first `.*` will slurp up everything it   can.  This is always the case, not just in `read.pattern`.

Comment: The keyword for that is *backtracing* :)

Comment: Added second solution.

Comment: +100 for the `read.table` version for this use-case. it's _substantially_ faster than the other two.